# Localhost works, but Heroku throws 500 when uploading photo with active_storage and Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to do a basic photo upload with ActiveStorage and Rails 5.2.  It works perfectly on `localhost` but runs into a 500 error when I try to create a new object in Heroku.  Unfortunately, the Heroku logs aren't being helpful at all:

```
2018-08-11T20:06:44.886851+00:00 app[web.1]: http://mab-staging.herokuapp.com/products/new -> /products
2018-08-11T20:06:44.886308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/products" host=mab-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=6557c78a-fbc1-4059-9904-c4b1122f8930 fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=79ms status=302 bytes=1304 protocol=http
2018-08-11T20:06:45.143034+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/products" host=mab-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=46ba7cc2-953a-4236-806c-44248a9625fe fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=153ms status=500 bytes=1262 protocol=http
2018-08-11T20:06:45.143727+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.204.125 - - [11/Aug/2018:20:06:44 UTC] "GET /products HTTP/1.1" 500 939
2018-08-11T20:06:45.143819+00:00 app[web.1]: http://mab-staging.herokuapp.com/products/new -> /products
2018-08-11T20:06:45.667492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mab-staging.herokuapp.com request_id=752f97ad-deea-41ed-af16-5a9c67f0329c fwd="68.225.227.137" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=304 bytes=133 protocol=http
2018-08-11T20:06:45.668380+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.7.204.125 - - [11/Aug/2018:20:06:45 UTC] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 0
2018-08-11T20:06:45.668476+00:00 app[web.1]: http://mab-staging.herokuapp.com/products -> /favicon.ico
```

I have all the steps included in [this](https://blog.heroku.com/rails-active-storage) Heroku documentation/tutorial.

I have installed ActiveStorage and ran `rake db:migrate` locally and on Heroku.

My `products#create` and `products#update` methods are like this:

```
 def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    @product.product_image.attach(params[:product][:product_image])
    @product.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your product has been created!"
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.product_image.attach(params[:product][:product_image])
    if @product.update_attributes(product_params)
      redirect_to products_path
      flash[:notice] = "That product has been updated."
    else
      render :action => :edit
      flash[:alert] = "Something went terribly wrong there..."
    end
  end
```

My form field is simple:

```
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
      <%= f.file_field :product_image %>
    </div> <!-- form group -->
```

I have the following in my `Gemfile` and have run `bundle install` and `bundle update`:

```
gem 'activestorage'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3' #AWS
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
```

I have this in `production.rb` and `staging.rb`:

```
  # Store files on Amazon S3.
  config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

And this in `storage.yml`:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  region: <%= ENV['AWS_REGION'] %>
  bucket: <%= ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] %>
```

I did this, even though I don't completely understand what it does:

```
 heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-activestorage-preview
```

I have this in my `product.rb` model:

```
has_one_attached :product_image
```

Can anyone see any reason this is working locally but not on Heroku?  I'm tapped...

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**

After some `heroku logs` assistance, I have more detailed logs:

```
2018-08-11T21:16:51.614163+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 139ms (ActiveRecord: 21.6ms)
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617425+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617550+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (to_model delegated to attachment, but attachment is nil):
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617809+00:00 app[web.1]: 3:   <div class="row">
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617812+00:00 app[web.1]: 4:     <div class="col-sm-3 text-center">
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617814+00:00 app[web.1]: 5:       <% if product.product_image %>
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617819+00:00 app[web.1]: 6:         <%= image_tag url_for(product.product_image), alt: product.name, style: "max-width: 100%; max-height: 200px" %>
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617822+00:00 app[web.1]: 7:       <% end %>
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617823+00:00 app[web.1]: 8:     </div>
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617825+00:00 app[web.1]: 9:
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617878+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617936+00:00 app[web.1]: app/views/products/_product_row.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_products__product_row_html_erb__1069905907297071252_46241260'
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617938+00:00 app[web.1]: app/views/products/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_products_index_html_erb___2131941533006009981_47014040'
2018-08-11T21:16:51.617940+00:00 app[web.1]: app/views/products/index.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_products_index_html_erb___2131941533006009981_47014040'
2018-08-11T21:16:51.630658+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.148.82.74 - - [11/Aug/2018:21:16:51 UTC] "GET /products HTTP/1.1" 500 939
2018-08-11T21:16:51.630751+00:00 app[web.1]: https://www.manlyartofbbq.com/products/new -> /products
```

Unfortunately, it looks like this is saying the attachment is `nil`, even though it shouldn't be, so for some reason the `product_image` isn't getting uploaded properly...

Comment: Make sure Rails is configured to log to standard output for error backtraces. Did you upgrade this app from an older version of Rails to 5.2? If so, check that your production config accounts for `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT`: https://blog.heroku.com/container_ready_rails_5#stdout-logging

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn It was upgraded from 4.2.  I made the change you recommended, but it didn't change anything in terms of errors or how the log reported it...

Comment: You may also need to set the `RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT` environment variable to `enabled` in your Heroku settings. (Sorry, I thought the Heroku buildpack would handle that, but maybe it doesn’t for upgraded apps.)

Comment: @GeorgeClaghorn That is very useful and I updated the OP with the newly revealed logs.  (Still stuck, but now with more of a clue as to why.)

Comment: You are uploading the images to an s3 bucket correct?  How are you linking to that URL in the s3 bucket?   Have you verified that the images are showing up in s3?

Comment: A few things: 1) Run `heroku config` to verify that all ENV vars specified in `storage.yml` are actually set. 2) Change `@product.save` to `@product.save!` since you're not handling a failure path (you have no idea when it fails). 3) Tail your logs when you're submitting the form to see what's happening with the attachment.

Comment: i am getting the same issue do you solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue never really got resolved, but I sidestepped it by deleting my database records for the table in question and re-uploading them.  It appears to have been a conversion from Paperclip-uploaded photos to ActiveStorage-uploaded photos issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code in production.rb

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if product.product_image %>
  <%= image_tag url_for(product.product_image), alt: product.name, style: "max-width: 100%; max-height: 200px" %>
<% end %>
```

In the above code, `product.product_image returns truthy even when there is no attached images. Just change the condition to

```
<% if product.product_image.attached? %>
  <%= image_tag url_for(product.product_image), alt: product.name, style: "max-width: 100%; max-height: 200px" %>
<% end %>
```